# Confirmation before closing a modal dialog page in Apex 5.0

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I am trying to create a simple confirmation ("Do you want to close this window?") when closing a modal dialog page with the (X)-button.

What would be the most efficient way to implement this in Apex 5.0?

I tried to implement a solution using the dialog closed event, this seemed to have had no effects on closing the dialog with the (X)-button, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to create a dynamic action, on page load, in your modal page with that code:

Your da should execute a javascript code:

```
var button = parent.$('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close'); //get the button
button.unbind(); //remove the behavior

//put another behavior to the button
button.on('click', function() {
   apex.message.confirm( "Your message here", function( okPressed ) { 
      if( okPressed ) {
          apex.navigation.dialog.cancel(true);
      }
   });
});
```

Try to confirm if the "X" button have the css class "ui-dialog-titlebar-close", they can change between versions of apex. 
If necessary, update the first line of the code with the correct class.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered hiding the button (x) and canceling the modal dialog page by clicking on the "cancel" button?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rename the standard button names in the confirmation window, use:

```
apex.lang.addMessages({"APEX.DIALOG.OK": pOkLabel});
apex.lang.addMessages({"APEX.DIALOG.CANCEL": pCancelLabel});
```